# partial matching of strings in different two datasets to obtain a match with higher frequency

Tags: r, dplyr, merge, match

I have strings in two datasets and i would like to do a partial match. Here is the code that I have written

```
 df1 <- data.frame(A=c(.87,.11,.44,.45), B=c("I have a beard", "I slept for two hours", "I have had two courses","this is not true"))

 df2 <- data.frame(X=c(127,10,433,344,890,4),Y=c("have","beard","syllabus","true","three","maths"))
```

I want to do a pmatch and I am expecting output as follows

```
  A     B                            X      Y
.87   I have a beard               127      have
.11   I slept for two hours        NA       NA
.44   I have had two courses       127      have
.45   this is not true             344      true
```

I would like to a partial match with a left join on df1. I want to get the higher of the two matches(for example in "I have a beard" string "have" match has 127 and "beard" has 10 and i want to get the higher match. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `dplyr` method doesn't need a `join` (which is reasonable as you don't have a common column to join on). It combines the 2 datasets and finds the matches. As long as you don't have thousands of rows it will work fast enough. Of course you can make the script smaller, but you can run this step by step to see how it works.

```
df1<- data.frame(A=c(.87,.11,.44,.45), B=c("I have a beard", "I slept for two hours", "I have had two courses","this is not true"))

df2<- data.frame(X=c(127,10,433,344,890,4),Y=c("have","beard","syllabus","true","three","maths"))

library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  do(data.frame(.,df2)) %>%                    # combine datasets
  do(data.frame(.,flag = grepl(.$Y,.$B))) %>%  # for each row check if there's a match and name it flag
  ungroup %>%
  group_by(A,B) %>%                            # for each A and B
  mutate(N=sum(flag)) %>%                      # count how many matches you have
  filter(flag==TRUE | N == 0) %>%              # keep only A,B where you have some matches or no match at all
  top_n(1,X) %>%                               # pick one row based on max value of X
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(Y = ifelse(flag==FALSE,NA,as.character(Y)),   # if there's no match replace Y with NA
         X = ifelse(flag==FALSE,NA,X)) %>%             # if there's no match replace X with NA
  select(-c(flag,N)) 


#      A                      B   X    Y
# 1 0.87         I have a beard 127 have
# 2 0.11  I slept for two hours  NA   NA
# 3 0.44 I have had two courses 127 have
# 4 0.45       this is not true 344 true
```

Try to experiment and change various column values to see how it works. You might be able to spot any bugs in advance.

Comment: Awesome! It worked like a charm though it took a while :)

Comment: @user3570187 There should not be a value for row 2 (890 is where `Y == three` which is not the case)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I forgot to replace X values with NAs as well. Will fix it asap.

Comment: @AntoniosK I understand what you are trying to do, but it feels overly convoluted. From what I understand you simply need to split the string , find the maximum value and `left_join` with df1.

Comment: Definitely more elegant and (most likely) faster than mine. I was afraid of cases where the text is not "clean" enough. Something like instead of having "I have a beard" to have "Ihave a beard", where "Ihave" will be considered as one word without match in `df2`. Of course, my method will find a match between words "have" and "behave", that's why I mentioned try to spot some bugs. I also think that both methods will fail to work with capital letters like "Have I a beard", right? I think there's also need for a process than makes everything lowercase (or uppercase).

Comment: Indeed, there could be text pre-processing, but that wasn't part of OP question.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(X = sapply(strsplit(as.character(B), ' '), 
                    function(x) with(df2, max(X[Y %in% x])))) %>%
  left_join(., df2)
```

Which gives:

```
#Joining by: "X"
#     A                      B    X    Y
#1 0.87         I have a beard  127 have
#2 0.11  I slept for two hours -Inf <NA>
#3 0.44 I have had two courses  127 have
#4 0.45       this is not true  344 true
```